# loading polymer element from custom package

Tags: html, dart, package, dart-polymer, observable

My problem is that **observable and published variables from polymer-elements are not working**. More precisely, they are not working if I **imported the elements from a package**. They are displayed correctly, but they do not react if their value changed.
If i load the same element directly from the main project everything works fine!

I published the complete **project on github.com** and added a README --> [here](https://github.com/DerWischer/polymer_problem)

### So this is what i have done:

I created a package which contains a polymer-element.
The package is called **foo_package** and my polymer-element uses foo.html and foo.dart. 
It is named **poly-foo**.

**foo_package structure**

[image: foo_package structure]

Now I create a new project and prepare everything for using polymer-elements. 
In yaml i add a dependency to my package

**pubspec.yaml**

```
[...]
dependencies:
  foo_package: 
    path: D:\User\UserName\dart\foo_package
[...]
```

Now I import foo.html in my html file

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/foo_package/foo.html">
```

and implement my custom tag

```
<poly-foo></poly-foo>
```

Finally I run my main file and everything looks alright. My element gets displayed the way i want it.
**But observables and published variables are not working.**

**What am I doing wrong?**

**foo.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="poly-foo"> 
  <template>

    Counter:{{counter}}
    <button on-click="{{increment}}">Up!</button>

  <script type="application/dart" src="foo.dart"></script>
  </template>  
</polymer-element>
```

**foo.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('poly-foo')
class PolyFoo extends PolymerElement {
  @observable int counter = 0;

  PolyFoo.created() : super.created();

  void increment(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    counter = counter + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, is the problem solved?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Polymer transformer configuration in you library package (doesn't need any entry points though)

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
```

Comment: I knew this but it was a bit tricky because you have to kill `pub serve` to make the change take effect (when `pub serve` was running while making the change) and I forgot to do that - took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: Solved!Thank you a lot, Günter!